# how work property in python and how it's impelment

Tags: python, properties

First, I apologize for my poor English
I have 3 questions

1. How can I see the property implementation?
2. Why should we write self.age as self._age .why we use _ ???
   And why does it give an error if we don't define setattr?
   Can't the variable be read only?

```
class test:
    def __init__(self):
        self.age = 20
    @property 
    def age(self):  
        return self._age # why use "_" without "_" give error
    @age.setter
    def age(self,v):
        self._age = v
        
  
o = test()
o.age
```

3. and last plz explain the following code.
   Why two doesn't return 2?

```
@property
def two():
    return 2

two  # why two is ==> <property at 0x18f49b93650>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I see the property implementation?

`@property` is a built-in for creating descriptors. If you're using CPython, you can find the implementation [over here in `descrobject.c`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/df7c8b95372169fb9d23140d35f91970ba32189d/Objects/descrobject.c#L1479) (along with a neat pure-Python version in a comment too!)

I would also recommend (re-)reading the [tutorial on descriptors](https://docs.python.org/3.10/howto/descriptor.html) so you can get a hang of how they work.

> Why should we write self.age as self._age .why we use _ ???

Because `self.age` is the property itself, and attempting to access it in the property getter leads to an infinite loop. That's why you need a different property for the "backing field". A property with a leading underscore is [conventionally](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/) meant to signify "non-public".

> and last plz explain the following code. Why two doesn't return 2?

```
@property
def two():
    return 2

two
```

See the descriptor tutorial. Only class attribute access is modified by the descriptor protocol; decorating a free function with `@property` does nothing useful.

Comment: tnx ..can answer this too..Can be variable read only by using property or another method?

Comment: Properties aren't writable unless you define a setter.

Answer (score 0):

> Why should we write self.age as self._age .why we use _ ???

Convention is as [PEP8](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/) puts it

> Use one leading underscore only for non-public methods and instance
> variables.

So when someone sees `_`-prefixed attribute knows it is used internally and generally should not be set directly, as this might e.g. bypass some checks in setter.

Comment: That doesn't answer OP's "why without _ give error" (to which the answer is "infinite recursion").